# Why are the attributes for the object not being returned

Tags: python, tree, depth-first-search

So i was solving the following question on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum/.
but i am unable to compile the code i believe my logic is not at fault here

```
class Solution:
    def hasPathSum(self, r: Optional[TreeNode], t: int) -> bool:
        sum_=0
        stc=[[r,sum_]]

        while stc:
            r1=stc.pop()
            
            if r1[0].val!=None:
                r1[1]+=r1[0].val
                if sum==t and r1[0].left==r1[1].right==None:
                    return True 
                else:
                    stc.extend([[r1[0].left,r1[1]],[r1[0].right,r1[1]]])
```

the error i am getting is as below and in the photo [compilation of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrj4A.png)

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
if r1[0].val!=None:
Line 18 in hasPathSum (Solution.py)
ret = Solution().hasPathSum(param_1, param_2)
Line 53 in _driver (Solution.py)
_driver()
Line 64 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: That error message isn't coming from the code you posted. It says `self.r`, the code just has `r`.

Comment: `sum==t` should be `sum_==t`

Comment: You need to check if `r1[0]` is not `None` before trying to use `r1[0].val`

Comment: `if r1[0] and r1[0].val is not None:`